# Creating strings with jinja structure inside

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm trying to generate django code, however when trying to create the templates,

```
classname = 'person'
content = "<a href='{% url 'core.views.add_%s' %}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{% trans 'Add' %}</a>\n" % classname
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: %u format: a number is required, not unicode
```

Python tries to evaluate the "{% u" and I get that error.
I tried also with "format" but error stays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can double encode jinja's `%` characters:

```
content = "<a href='{%% url 'core.views.add_%s' %%}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{%%  trans 'Add' %%}</a>\n" % classname
```

or double encode Jinjas `{}` characters and use `format()`:

```
content = "<a href='{{% url 'core.views.add_{classname}' %}}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{{% trans 'Add' %}}</a>\n".format(classname=classname)
```

Or simply split your template into three parts:

```
content = "<a href='{% url 'core.views.add_"
content += '%s' % classname
cotnent += " %}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{% trans 'Add' %}</a>\n"
```

Comment: Either way it's ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do simple string concatenation in this case:

```
content = "<a href='{% url 'core.views.add_" + classname + "' %}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{% trans 'Add' %}</a>\n"
```

Example:

```
>>> classname = 'person'
>>> content = "<a href='{% url 'core.views.add_" + classname + "' %}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{% trans 'Add' %}</a>\n"
>>> content
>>> '<a href=\'{% url \'core.views.add_person %}\' class="btn btn-default">{% trans \'Add\' %}</a>\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a literal `%` in your string, use two percent signs `%%`:

```
"<a href='{%% url 'core.views.add_%s' %%}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{%% trans 'Add' %%}</a>\n" % classname
```

If you use the `format()` method, you need to use `{{` and `}}`:

```
"<a href='{{% url 'core.views.add_{}' %}}' class=\"btn btn-default\">{{% trans 'Add' %}}</a>\n".format(classname)
```